# Transparent table view over map

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, ios7

I am trying to put a transparent table view over a map.  First, I set backgroundcolor as clearColor and it didn't work. Then I set alpha on the table view as 0.5 then it is transparent but text in labels also transparent.  I want to see through the map but text in label should stand out. I reset the alpha on the label but it is still not effective.  How can I do this in iOS7?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the background color of each table cell as clearColor. Set this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Brilliant.  This suggestion worked.  So, to be clear, I set background of tableview to be clearColor, then background of cell to be clearColor.  Then it worked. Thanks! Sorry I don't have enough reputation to give you up vote.  I will come back and change it later once I am qualified for.  But your answer is accepted.